# Update Trigger Affecting Too Many Rows

Tags: sql

I wrote the following trigger:

```
begin

update NFL.TeamStatistics

set Passing_Yards = (select sum(Quarterbacks.Yards) 
                     from NFL.Quarterbacks 
                     where Quarterbacks.Team = inserted.Team)

from NFL.Quarterbacks 
            inner join inserted on Quarterbacks.Team = inserted.Team;
```

Whenever someone updates the passing yards in the table about quarterbacks, it should automatically set `NFL.TeamStatistics.Passing_Yards` to the sum of each team's passing yards.

I used the following update statement to test it:

```
update NFL.Quarterbacks

set Quarterbacks.Yards = 4000

where Team = 'PIT';
```

However, in the table `NFL.TeamStatistics` it set the `passingyards` for all teams to 4000 instead of just for `PIT`.  What is the matter?

Comment: there is no where clause for the update statement, to it would update NFL.TeamStatistics table

Comment: FYI, this is an after update trigger.

Comment: I believe I put the where clause after sum(Quarterbacks.Yards).  Should I have placed it somewhere else?

Comment: add this  where Quarterbacks.Team = inserted.Team before your "semi-colon" ; and run the query, if it works then I'll post it as an answer

Comment: So after = inserted.Team and before the semi-colon?

Comment: That didn't do the trick.  Instead, took the sum of all quarterback's passing yards and set that as the passing_yards in the TeamStatistics table.

Comment: you need to specify and column in NFL.TeamStatistics that you want to compare to

Comment: I have a question for you.  I wrote the following statement in my original coding:

Comment: Can I add it as an answer and get a vote for it??

Comment: Yeah sure.  I'm sorry I didn't respond to you earlier, I was away from my computer.

Comment: added can I get the vote and mark it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a where clause and column in NFL.TeamStatistics that you want to compare to

e.g:

```
 begin

update NFL.TeamStatistics

set Passing_Yards = (select sum(Quarterbacks.Yards) 
                     from NFL.Quarterbacks 
                     where Quarterbacks.Team = inserted.Team)

from NFL.Quarterbacks 
            inner join inserted on Quarterbacks.Team = inserted.Team
where Team = Quarterbacks.Team;
```

Assuming you were comparing to Quaterbacks.Team

Answer (score 0):

You should use where clause in your update statement in order to filter data you are going to update.